# Gatsby MDX showing title and slug but doesn't find page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm learning Gatsby and I wanted to use MDX for blog pages. I followed the tutorial [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/mdx/programmatically-creating-pages/) to programmatically create pages.

I can see them in my GraphQL, and displaying the list of all the articles is working with their title and slug, but when I click on the link to open them or type their address I have a 404 page. Do you have an idea from where it can come from?

This is my code:

gatsby-node.js:

```
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
    const { createNodeField } = actions

    if (node.internal.type === "Mdx") {
        const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode })

        createNodeField({
            name: "slug",
            node,
            value: `/blog${value}`,
        })
    }
}
```

gatsby-config.js:

```
plugins: [
        {
        resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
        options: {
            defaultLayouts: { default: path.resolve('./src/layouts/post.js') },
            extensions: [`.mdx`, `.md`],
        },
    },

    {
        resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
        options: {
            name: `posts`,
            path: `${__dirname}/src/posts`
        }
    },
],
```

index.js (with the list):

```
<ul>
    {posts.map(({ node: post }) => (
        <li key={post.id}>
            <Link to={post.fields.slug}>
                <h2>{post.frontmatter.title}</h2>
            </Link>
            <p>{post.excerpt}</p>
        </li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

Query in index.js

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
    query blogIndex {
        allMdx {
            edges {
                node {
                    id
                    excerpt
                    frontmatter {
                        title
                    }
                    fields {
                        slug
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
`
```

The template:

```
<div>
    <div className="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.html }}></div>
</div>
```

And the query for the template:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
    query BlogPostQuery($id: String) {
        mdx(id: { eq: $id }) {
            id
            body
            frontmatter {
                title
            }
        }
    }
`
```

I made a repo if you want to test it: https://github.com/JulSeb42/gatsby-mdx

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the page creation part. In your `gatsby-node.js` add the following:

```
const path = require("path")

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
  // Destructure the createPage function from the actions object
  const { createPage } = actions

  const result = await graphql(`
    query {
      allMdx {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild('  ERROR: Loading "createPages" query')
  }

  // Create blog post pages.
  const posts = result.data.allMdx.edges

  // you'll call `createPage` for each result
  posts.forEach(({ node }, index) => {
    createPage({
      // This is the slug you created before
      // (or `node.frontmatter.slug`)
      path: node.fields.slug,
      // This component will wrap our MDX content
      component: path.resolve(`./src/components/posts-page-layout.js`),
      // You can use the values in this context in
      // our page layout component
      context: { id: node.id },
    })
  })
}
```

Regarding your other issue, it should be a separate question but, if a component is exported as default, you don't need the curly braces when importing it. In addition, you need to return a value.

Comment: If the issue has been solved please accept the answer to close the issue.